# Understanding schematron validation

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema, schematron

I am new to xml and I am having difficulties in understanding what is happening in the below statement. The Schematron file is from https://schemas.wmo.int/iwxxm/3.0.0/rule/iwxxm.sch

```
<sch:rule context="//*[contains(name(),'MeteorologicalAerodromeTrendForecast')]/iwxxm:weather">
<sch:assert test="@xlink:href = document('codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf')/rdf:RDF/*/skos:member/*/@*[local-name()='about'] or @nilReason">
MeteorologicalAerodromeTrendForecast iwxxm:weather elements should be a member of http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather
</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

I understand that there is a rule to check the element `iwxxm:weather`, but i am unable to understand the test condition. Can anyone explain it to me please? For what value, the test will pass.

The test is failing at a line in the xml which is

```
<iwxxm:MeteorologicalAerodromeForecast gml:id="uuid.c42e9861-aed6-449f-b4cd-4789e96464d5" cloudAndVisibilityOK="false">
          <iwxxm:prevailingVisibility uom="m">350</iwxxm:prevailingVisibility>
          <iwxxm:surfaceWind>
            <iwxxm:AerodromeSurfaceWindForecast variableWindDirection="false">
              <iwxxm:meanWindDirection uom="deg">240</iwxxm:meanWindDirection>
              <iwxxm:meanWindSpeed uom="[kn_i]">8</iwxxm:meanWindSpeed>
            </iwxxm:AerodromeSurfaceWindForecast>
          </iwxxm:surfaceWind>
 Here ---->         <iwxxm:weather xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather/_RA"/> 
          <iwxxm:cloud>
```

Thanks

Comment: change `contains(name(),'MeteorologicalAerodromeTrendForecast')` to `contains(local-name(),'MeteorologicalAerodromeTrendForecast')`.

Comment: The Schematron file is from https://schemas.wmo.int/iwxxm/3.0.0/rule/iwxxm.sch and I cannot change the file. I am validating my file against this schematron file and getting these errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schematron assertion is verifying that one of the following two conditions are met:

1. the `xlink:href` attribute value of the `iwxxm:weather` context element is equal to that of the `about` attribute from a particular RDF document:

   - The [`document()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PER-xslt20-20090421/#function-document) function is used to access an external XML document. In this case, it is the `codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf` RDF document.
   - Then it applies an XPath to select the attribute that has a local-name of `about` (doesn't matter if it is bound to a namespace or not)
   - that is attached to an element (doesn't matter what the name of the element is)
   - that is the child of a `skos:member` element
   - that is the child of an element (doesn't matter what the name of the element is)
   - that is the child of the `rdf:RDF` document element.

For instance, if the RDF document looked like this:

```
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
           xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#">
  <foo>
    <skos:member>
      <bar skos:about="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather/_RA"/>
    </skos:member>
  </foo>
</rdf:RDF>
```

2. or the `iwxxm:weather` context element has a `nilReason` attribute

For instance, if the element were to look like this:

```
<iwxxm:weather nilReason="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

given the target node:

```
<iwxxm:weather xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather/_RA"/>
```

and the assertion test:

```
@xlink:href = document('codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf')/rdf:RDF/*/skos:member/*/@*[local-name()='about'] or @nilReason
```

it compares the value of `iwxxm:weather/@xlink:href` and `document('codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf')/rdf:RDF/*/skos:member/*/@*[local-name()='about']`, since this is an assertion, it returns true if the compared values do not match OR `iwxxm:weather` does not have an attribute `@nilReason`.

It will pass if `iwxxm:weather/@xlink:href` and `document('codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf')/rdf:RDF/*/skos:member/*/@*[local-name()='about']` is an equal match or `iwxxm:weather` should have an attribute `@nilReason`.

Comment: can you please explain the xpath expression document('codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf')/rdf:RDF/*/skos:member/*/@*[local-name()='about']

Comment: `document('codes.wmo.int-49-2-AerodromePresentOrForecastWeather.rdf')` gets the resource, then traverses the contents up to `/rdf:RDF/*/skos:member/*/@*[local-name()='about']`